How to Proxy Two Services Under a Single Subdomain Using Nginx Without Modifying Upstream Configurations?
When I use Nginx for reverse proxy, the typical approach is to assign a subdomain to each service. This way, each service can handle URIs starting from /. For example, the configuration looks like this:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name share.example.cn;

    ssl_certificate      "/etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.cn/cert.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.cn/key.pem";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://shlink:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name link.example.cn;

    ssl_certificate      "/etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.cn/cert.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.cn/key.pem";

    location / {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/link.example.cn/;
        index index.html;
    }
}

However, this setup is a bit inconvenient because the services (which are a frontend and a backend) are split between two subdomains. This causes difficulties such as cross-origin issues. Therefore, I want to serve them under the same subdomain.
I modified the configuration to add /admin/ as a context path for the frontend:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name link.example.cn;

    ssl_certificate      "/etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.cn/cert.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.cn/key.pem";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://shlink:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/link.example.cn/;
        index index.html;
    }
}

However, this introduces a problem: the upstream service doesn't know that it should prepend /admin to its URIs. As a result, while index.html is accessible, any requests for static assets are made to the root (e.g., /server, /setting), which leads to failed routing. This means the configuration is not working as expected.

The constraint is that I cannot modify the upstream service configuration or I only have access to pre-built static files.

Given these constraints, is there a way to proxy both services under the same subdomain using Nginx? This issue has been troubling me for quite a while, and I would appreciate any help or suggestions.
What I Tried:
I added the /admin/ context to the frontend service using alias, hoping this would allow the static assets to be served correctly.
I ensured that both the frontend and backend would be accessible under the same subdomain, expecting the frontend to adjust its asset paths automatically.
What I Expected:
I expected that by adding the /admin/ context, the frontend would prepend /admin to all static resource requests, allowing assets and routes to function properly.
What Actually Happened:
The frontend still attempted to load static resources and routes from the root path (e.g., /server, /setting), ignoring the /admin prefix, resulting in failed requests and broken routing.
